# VPN location with Smartphone

Tags: geolocation, smartphone

My company logs the location of where you VPN from.  If I use my smartphone hotspot would the VPN be able to see if I'm at home or at the beach?

Comment: Questions about phones are off topic here, see the [faq]. Anyway, if you are using the VPN you are not at work yet still, theoretically, working. Why should they care where you are? Oh, and if they _do_ check the location, they probably do it via IP geolocation, I doubt they are accessing your phone's GPS chip.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The short answer is that it could be possible. The two ways they could be logging your location is by your IP address or GPS readings from the phone.

If they are logging your IP address there is little chance of them tracking you down. Your network provider changes your phone's IP address all the time so it would be hard to notice anything out of the ordinary. I suppose its possible the IP the phone network gives you is based on location and that the company actually geolocates the IPs but thats a bit of a stretch.

The alternative is that they are accessing GPS readings from the phone. In this case it would be very simple for the company to see where you are. However, its extremely unlikely that your employer would go to this
length to track you.

So while its possible, there's a pretty good chance they'd never know...they expect their employees to be trustworthy

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a very good question. Yahoo's CEO viewed the VPN logs to see who was working from home and who was not. She came to the conclusion that most of her staff were not so pulled the plug on remote working.

There was also a developer who outsourced his work to China. He was only discovered when his IT dept noticed Chinese IP addresses and wrongly believed themselves to be attacked.

You could re-route your session via your home router. However, If you were called in and couldn't make it because you were abroad you might just get yourself in hot water. If the phone is not BYOD then as company property they could just remote access your phone and get your location [mostly used by enterprise level companies].

http://www.businessinsider.com/how-marissa-mayer-figured-out-work-at-home-yahoos-were-slacking-off-2013-3

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-21043693